# I have a dropdown and two radio buttons. Onload radio button 'A' is checked. on updating the dropdown value to 123 radio button B need to be checked

Tags: javascript, angular

dropdown has 4 values "All", "abc", "xya", "123","789". and I have two radio buttons A and B. Onload radio button A is checked. when I have changed the value of Dropdown to "123" radio button B need to be checked.

Can some one help me the solution in angular. Both dropdown and radio buttons are in child components and been called in the main component.

Comment: Not without you providing some example of the code you currently have.

Comment: Show us what you tried and where it failed or where you think it failed. I or anybody else will not code or debug for you without an effort from your side. We are here to help you, not work for you.